# vb.net decimal take first digit

Tags: vb.net, int, decimal, digit

I have problem about vb.net convert digit.
My variable as double "a" = 1.56
I wanna take the result 1.
If "a" have decimal above .5 or lower .4 take the first digit.

```
 ex: a=1.99
 result a=1

 ex2 : a=7.3
 result a=7
```

please help me and thanks for your concern

Comment: There's no inbuilt function to do that so you will have to perform some arithmetic.  As arithmetic is not a programming issue, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Dim i As Double = 21.55
        MsgBox(i.ToString.Substring(0, 1))

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for:
[Math Truncate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx)